# .htaccess URL Rewrite not working (trying to send GET data with it)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite a url that looks like http://example.com/View/(random_text) to take the user to http://example.com/View/site.php?site=(random_text)

This is what I am ussing so far:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^View/(.+)$ View/site.php?site=$1 [NC]
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you are doing correct

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)/View/(.+)$ /View/site.php?site=$2 [L,R=301]
```

If the "View" directory is in your webserver's root directory, then add just the single forward slash as above. Else add the path to the view directory like below:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/View/(.+)$ /path_to_view_directory/View/site.php?site=$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I'm just getting a 404 error on my server. Should I restart it after updating?  Maybe is there anything else I should do?

Comment: where is the "View" directory located in your webserver? Is it in the server root? If yes, you need to add the "/" before the "View". If no, you need to add the full path to the "View" directory. See the updated answer.

Comment: I've changed the last linke to this : RewriteRule ^(.*)/View/(.+)$ /var/etc/www/html/View/site.php?site=$2 [L,R=301]
However, it doesn't work still.